# sls deploying multiple IAM roles for lambda, which assumes wrong role with missing permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

i'm currently running a sls project that has 2 lambda functions. One pushes an item to dynamo, the other is triggered when an item is pushed to dynamo (stream). "Process lambda" -> DDB -> "Build lambda".

When testing locally with sls all the PutItem calls work. When `sls deploy` and testing live on aws, i get access denied issue:

```
assumed-role/app-client-onboarder-dev-us-east-2-lambdaRole/app-client-onboarder-dev-app_new_client_process is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:123456789:table/dev-app-clients
```

When i look into IAM, are 2 roles for this deployment (which i thought there'd be only 1)

1. arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/AppClient-dev-BuildProcessLambdaExecutionRole
2. arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/app-client-onboarder-dev-us-east-2-lambdaRole

It looks like the assumed role above is `assumed-role/role 1./role 2.`

- The first one is defined in resources (see at bottom) with the seperated policies
- The second one looks to be built for this cf/sls deployment - this one has a single policy with multiple statements, is missing key permissions (like dynamodb:PutItem).

**What am I missing w/r/t new Roles and policies with sls, having the deployed lambdas assume the defined roles? Where does this second 'deployment' level role come from?**

exerpt of `serverless.yml` is found below.

```
service: app-client-onboarder


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-2
  stage: dev

functions:
  app_new_client_process:
    handler: lambda/handler.app_new_client_process
    tracing: true
    environment:
      DynamoClientTableName: ${self:custom.client-table-name.${self:provider.stage}}
      DynamoDataTableNamePrefix: ${self:custom.client-data-table-name-prefix.${self:provider.stage}}

  app_new_client_build_resources:
    handler: lambda/handler.app_new_client_build_resources
    tracing: true
    events:
      - stream: ${self:custom.client-table-updates.${self:provider.stage}}
    environment:
      DynamoClientTableName: ${self:custom.client-table-name.${self:provider.stage}}
      DynamoDataTableNamePrefix: ${self:custom.client-data-table-name-prefix.${self:provider.stage}}


resources:
  Resources: 
    appClientBuildProcessLambdaExecutionRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: appClient-${self:provider.stage}-BuildProcessLambdaExecutionRole
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        Policies:
        - PolicyName: appClientDynamoDBIamPolicy
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
                  - "dynamodb:GetItem"
                  - "dynamodb:PutItem"
                  - "dynamodb:DescribeStream"
                  - "dynamodb:ListStreams"
                  - "dynamodb:ListTables"
                Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:146449424444:table/*app-client*"
        - PolicyName: appLogsIamPolicy
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                  - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                  - "logs:PutLogEvents"
                Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:146449424444:*"
        - PolicyName: appXrayTracingPolicy
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "xray:PutTraceSegments"
                  - "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
                Resource: "*"

plugins: 
  - serverless-plugin-tracing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the role name defined in resources to the appropriate scope.

At `provider` level:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-2
  stage: dev
  role: AppExRole
```

or `function` level if each function have a different set of permissions

```
functions
  f1:
    role: AppExRole
  f2:
    role: AppExRole2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define permissions for your Serverless Project under provider -> iamRoleStatements as:

```
provider:

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "dynamodb:Query" 
        - "dynamodb:PutItem"
        - "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
      Resource: YOUR_DYNAMODB_ARN
```